# Visual Studio 2012 Corrupting ApplicationHost.config File

Tags: visual-studio-2012

I just installed Visual Studio 2012 RTM.  During the process of trying to create a new web project, I receive the following error:

"Web application projects are currently configured to use IIS Express.  To switch back to using the Visual Studio Development server, change the development server option under the Projects and Solutions/Web Projects category of the Tools/Options menu.  Configuring IIS Express failed with the following error:  Filname: \?\UNC\DEV-FILES\home\mike\MyDocuments\IISExpress\config\applicationHost.config. Line number:1. Error: Configuration file is not well formed XML"

...and project creation subsequently fails.

I already know that I can resolve the this by using the VS dev server, but I should also be able to use IIS when necessary.

When I view the applicationHost file in question, its size is 0kb. It looks like Visual Studio 2012 wiped the contents of the file completely out.  I've taken clean backups of the applicationHost file from c:/inetpub/history/ and restored them in the IISExpress folder.  Again, when I attempt to create a new project through VS 2012, the file goes from 85KB back down to 0KB.

So I guess I'm trying to figure out why VS 2012 is writing to the applicationHost.config file, what it's trying to write, and how I can resolve the issue.

Thanks,
Mike

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem and solved it by removing encryption on the IISExpress folder. You may or may not need to remove encryption on your My Documents\Visual Studio 2012 folder as well.

Comment: This answer had -1 next to it, so I marked it up as it solved my issue..  Thanks @user6374..